# Show next two days that events occur on

Tags: views, 10

I've revisited this multiple times, and have yet to figure this out.

I have a calendar with events on it. No event ever spans multiple days. There are also days that do not have events.

I'm trying to figure out how to shows days that only have events, and then list the next two days worth of events using a View. It's possible in the future we will want to display the next 3 days worth of events.

For instance, if Mon and Thurs have events, I want to list those. Wed, Fri, and Saturday do not have events, but it's possible they could next week.

Right now I am achieving this by showing the next 7 days worth of events in the View. Somewhere in that 7 day range, it's possible that two of the days have events. But not always. Sometimes every day in that 7 day range has events, and in these cases, the list is very very long. Too long. Which is why I only want to get the next two days that events fall on.

It might end up being something I need to code myself, and if so, I can do that. It would be nice if this were adjustable in views, however.

Any thoughts on this?